# How can I create a listener for ArcSoftEventProvider using Python?

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, etw

I was trying to create a listener for camera events (turn on, turn off).

I found out whenever I turn my camera on/off, ArcSoftEventProvider reports certain events in Windows Event Viewer in my laptop (not regular PC) immediately. So I want to find a way to use this provider using Python.

[ArcSoftEventProvider in Windows Event Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZM21.png)

**Something I've tried:**

I tried the Python package ***pywintrace*** for Windows ETW events but it seems that I have to provide the GUID of ArcSoftEventProvider which I couldn't find.

***pywintrace***  example:

```
import etw


def some_func():
    # define capture provider info
    providers = [etw.ProviderInfo('Some Provider', etw.GUID("{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}"))]

    # create instance of ETW and start capture
    with etw.ETW(providers=providers, event_callback=etw.on_event_callback):
        # run capture
        etw.run('etw')
```

**So my problems are:**

1. Where can I find the GUID of ArcSoftEventProvider? I may still use ***pywintrace*** to capture the camera events if I find the GUID.
2. What is the alternative way to create a listener for ArcSoftEventProvider if I can't find the GUID?

Comment: *"Or if there is another way to do this?"* - You haven't actually explained what you're trying to accomplish. The question text reads like the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Hope my question makes more sense now.

Comment: You can use [logman](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/logman) to get a list of providers: `logman.exe query providers`. It's still not clear from the question what you are planning to do with the information. It could well be that ETW is the wrong technology altogether.

Comment: You can use the project [ETW Providers Docs](https://github.com/repnz/etw-providers-docs) to dump the provider information. But as @IInspectable said, *It could well be that ETW is the wrong technology altogether*.